# Converting depth image of type CV_16UC1 in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

The input image is a depth image having `CV_16UC1` encoding (depth values are in millimeter). I want to convert depth values to meters. Later on, I need depth values of a few pixels. Therefore, I am using the mat.at() to access the individual pixel locations. Finally, the depth value is multiplied by 0.001f to convert it to meters.

However, instead of multiplying the depth value after using the `mat.at()` function, I want to do it another way i.e. multiply the whole image by 0.001f and then use the `mat.at()` function. unfortunately, this is giving the wrong value. A sample code is shown below-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  cv::Mat img_mm(480, 640, CV_16UC1);

  // just for debugging
  randu(img_mm, cv::Scalar(0), cv::Scalar(1234));

  // assign a fixed value at (0, 0) just for debugging
  int pixel_x = 0;
  int pixel_y = 0;
  img_mm.at<unsigned short>(pixel_y, pixel_x) = 123;

  // the first way
  auto depth_mm = img_mm.at<unsigned short>(pixel_y, pixel_x);
  auto depth_m = depth_mm * 0.001f;

  // the second way
  cv::Mat img_m = img_mm * 0.001f;
  float depth_unsigned_short = img_m.at<unsigned short>(pixel_y, pixel_x);
  float depth_float = img_m.at<float>(pixel_y, pixel_x);

  std::cout << "depth_mm " << depth_mm << ", depth_m " << depth_m << ", depth_unsigned_short " << depth_unsigned_short << ", depth_float " << depth_float << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Below is the output-

```
depth_mm 123, depth_m 0.123, depth_unsigned_short 0, depth_float 9.18355e-41
```

I was expecting to see 0.123 in the second way. But we see that both `depth_unsigned_short` and `depth_float` are returning wrong values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use opencv provided matrix conversion utility.
Check [convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b)

Something like:

```
cv::mat f32Mat;
img_mm.convertTo(f32Mat,CV_32FC1,0.001);
```

should do the trick.

At least the following statement of your code is wrong assuming `img_m` is a float matrix.

```
float depth_unsigned_short = img_m.at<unsigned short>(pixel_y, pixel_x);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know convertTo function. Can you please tell me the output image type which is required in convertTo function?

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. I tried using `CV_16FC1` but it seems that `CV_16FC1` is unavailable in OpenCV 2.4.8. So I am using `CV_32FC1` as you suggested!